# Metrics in comparing the rank orders of elements from 2 vectors

Tags: similarities, wilcoxon-signed-rank, approximate-bayesian-computation

I am working on sampling a posterior distribution for parameters in my model using approximate Bayesian computation (ABC). I would like to come up with a summary statistic to compare the similarity/distance of ranked order between my simulated data and observed data. My observed data are a list of 10 species biomass. So I would like to compare the rank of species *i* between simulated and observed data, and summarize over 10 species.

My questions are:

1. Is there some metrics that can quantify the rank differences between 2 vectors? So far, what I did is to take the rank difference per species and calculate the sum of absolute difference across the 10 species.
2. Because the metric should provide a distance-like result: the more similar the 2 vector ranks, the smaller the value is. I am not sure if I can use the test statstics in Wilcoxon signed-rank test. Anyone has any comments?

Thanks very much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you use a simple Spearman correlation?  It will give you a rank-based correlations statistic with the benefit of having metric properties, I believe.

Comment: thanks very much. The Spearman rank correlation is exactly what I want

Answer (score 1):

Although this question has been finished, I still want to mention [the Kendall rank correlation coefficient](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kendall_rank_correlation_coefficient#:%7E:text=In%20statistics%2C%20the%20Kendall%20rank,association%20between%20two%20measured%20quantities). Personally, it accommodates the nature of ranks better and its intuition is very straightforward.